# jQuery basics (theory) - what can I do with index (i) parameter in .text(i, x), .html(i, x) or .val(i, x)?

Tags: jquery

I'm going through jQuery tutorial on ws3school. I understand how it works, but I cannot think in what way it can be used.

Example from website below or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_callback).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#test1").text(function(i, origText){
            return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + i + ")";
        });
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#test2").html(function(i, origText){
            return "Old html: " + origText + " New html: Hello <b>world!</b> (index: " + i + ")";
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Show Old/New Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Show Old/New HTML</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone could give an example? Code appreciated, but not necessary.

Comment: There are many ways you want to use an index for. For example, if you want a one-to-one correspondence between an element to another, related solely by their index (i.e. their position). You might want to limit the number of iterations when going through a collection. You might want to pick odd/even/every *n*-th child in your collection. So on, and so forth. I am voting to close because it only encourages opinion-based answers.

Comment: You really need to read, Jquery, through any of the online tutorial. This platform is not for tutorial. If you stuck some where during development, we are here for you.

Comment: it doesn't need to be used every time. It's an iterator. Let's say you want to highlight every second element (`i%2==0`) or something. There are lots of options. In this case `i` is useless as you have only one element.

Comment: `I'm going through jQuery tutorial on ws3school` please don't. The guides on the jQuery site are far more comprehensive (not to mention accurate and up to date) https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help bring practical meaning to it:

```js
var trial = 0;
function indexTrial(i, prevText) {
  //console.log(i + ': ' + prevText + ' (trial: ' + trial + ')');
  return prevText + ', (got <u>index ' + i + '</u> on trial ' + trial + ')';
}

trial++;
$('li').html(indexTrial);

trial++;
$('#second-list li').html(indexTrial);

trial++;
$('#second-list li:even').html(indexTrial);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="first-list">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>
  <li>ghi</li>
  <li>jkl</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<ul id="second-list">
  <li>123</li>
  <li>456</li>
  <li>789</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use it in a case like this:

```
$( "ul li" ).text(function( index ) {
  return "item number " + ( index + 1 );
});
```

Which means `.text(index)` might be useful when you use it in arrays.